# MySQL max date Generate Incorrect Output

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables.

```
letter table

letter_no   date    r_from  branch
1   2018-08-10  A   Admin
2   2018-08-10  B   Enginnering
3   2018-08-11  C   IT
4   2018-08-12  D   Admin

action table

action_id   letter  action_date status
1   1   2018-08-15  on-going
2   2   2018-08-12  on-going
3   1   2018-08-17  finished

desired output

letter_id   action_date status
1   2018-08-17  finished
2   2018-08-12  on-going
```

I used the following sql query to get the output

```
 SELECT letter.letter_id, MAX(action.action_date), action.status FROM action
    LEFT JOIN action ON action.letter_id=letter.letter_id
    GROUP BY action.letter_id
```

But the query generate the following output.

```
letter_id   action_date status
1   2018-08-15  on-going
2   2018-08-12  on-going
```

I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function inside a correlated sub-query, like this:

```
  select  * from action t1
   where t1.action_date in     
    (          
     select max(action_date) from action t2  
      where t2.letter=t1.letter
       )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02c4c/5

```
id  letter  action_date     status
2   2      2018-08-12       on-going
3   1      2018-08-17       finished
```

Answer (score 2):

For your query you do have two tables called `action` and do not have alias,and you also just compare the `letter_id` in `JOIN`,you also need to compare `action_date`

You can use below sql to do it

```
  SELECT a1.id,a1.letter_id,a1.action_date 
    FROM action a1
  JOIN
    (SELECT a.letter_id,max(a.action_date) as mdate 
         FROM action a GROUP BY a.letter_id) a2 
  ON a1.letter_id=a2.letter_id AND a1.action_date=a2.mdate
```